# Programmatically add columns to datagrid not compiling

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, multiple-columns

This is the continuation to

> [OnEvent datagrid column add fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293395/onevent-datagrid-column-add-fail)

I have seen this post:

> [How to add Data to a WPF datagrid programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950312/how-to-add-data-to-a-wpf-datagrid-programatically)

the datagrid is simply this:

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgResults" Background="Transparent" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
```

in which everything seems to work fine but when I put it in my solution it doesn't compile:

[image]

Can anyone explain me why?

---EDIT---

I realize now that I have misunderstood what's in the link above.
In short I have a datagrid binded to an observable collection. 
I have to add two more columns. How can that be done?

---EDIT2---- for CBreeze

```
 dtgResults.ItemsSource = obcmMyDim;<--------previous data here
 DataGridTextColumn textColumn1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
 textColumn1.Header = "AAA1";
 textColumn1.Binding = new Binding("AAA1");

 DataGridTextColumn textColumn2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
 textColumn2.Header = "AAA2";
 textColumn2.Binding = new Binding("AAA2");

 Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => dtgResults.Columns.Add(textColumn1)));
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => dtgResults.Columns.Add(textColumn2)));

 dtgResults.Items.Add(new { AAA1 = "Col1Row1", AAA2 = "Col2Row1"});
 dtgResults.Items.Add(new { AAA1 = "Col1Row2", AAA2 = "Col2Row2" });
```

---EDIT 3--- for JH
So in short I have that observable collection which binded to the datagrid make the following output:

[image]

then I add the columns with your method:

```
var names = obcmMyDim.First().obcItemsName; // All entries must have the same list of obcItemsName and in the same order
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
    {
      DataGridTextColumn c = new DataGridTextColumn();
      c.Header = names[i];

      var b = new Binding();
      string str = string.Format("obcmMyDim.obcItemsMeasured[{0}]", i);
      b.Path = new PropertyPath(str);
      b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

      c.Binding = b;

      dtgResults.Columns.Add(c);
    }
```

as for the binded array

[image]

[image]

and the bind str is  "obcmMyDim.obcItemsMeasured[0]" ...1....n

but what I get is that the columns are there but they are empty

[image]

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I would recommend using DataBinding instead of adding items one by one. If you're coming from WinForms, you should rethink the way you link the controls to actual data.

Comment: I can't get to do that. I have already posted the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290099/how-to-databing-datagrid-with-class-with-collection-and-modify-columns-according

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like;

```
dtgResults.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "a.1"});
dtgResults.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "a.2"});
```

**EDIT:**

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
 {
     dtgResults.Items.Add(new { a.1 = "Test" + i, a.2 = "Test" + i});
 }
```

Comment: For the header it's fine but how to add the values of the column?

Comment: @Patrick add a new item? `dtgResults.Items.Add(new { a.1 = "Test1", a.2 = "Test2" });`

Comment: The column is formed with a number of values according to the number of rows. So I am puzzled how can I add it as a single value??? I would expect something like a.1 = {"Col1Row1", "Col1Row2",.....}

Comment: VERY WELL!!! We are getting nearer. The only problem is that it doesn't add columns, it deleted all the columns and then add only the new ones.

Comment: @Patrick So programatically add the old ones in too? If you don't use `DataBinding` I assume this is what you have to do, hence why so many people suggest to use `DataBinding`. You just need to add the values into the loops, so `dtgResults.Items.Add(new { a.1 = "Test" + i, a.2 = "Test" + i, col3 = "Test" + i, col4 = "Test" +i etc etc});`

Comment: @Patrick there's no easy way round it - you're trying to do two different things the same way

Comment: No wait it's getting better by little steps. See the EDIT 3 pic. It's adding columns but they are empty.

Answer (score 0):

It does not compiling because you use `ItemCollection`. I think you did not create your own class like in answer from link and used `System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection`, which can`t used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to an item in an array but you'll have to make sure that all the arrays are the same (same fields, in the same order so that the index into them is consistent). Here is an example of it based on the other question you had.

Note that the field obcItemsMeasured had to be changed into a property since bindings require properties (not fields).

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dtgResults" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NameAxisDimension}" Header="NameAxisDimension" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Nominal}" Header="Nominal" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UpperTolerance}" Header="UpperTolerance" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LowerTolerance}" Header="LowerTolerance" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Build list of MyDimensions manually (since I don't have access to your data)
            var obcmMyDim = new ObservableCollection<MyDimension>(CreateData());
            dtgResults.ItemsSource = obcmMyDim;

            var names = obcmMyDim.First().obcItemsName; // All entries must have the same list of obcItemsName and in the same order
            for (int i=0; i<names.Count; i++)
            {
                DataGridTextColumn c = new DataGridTextColumn();
                c.Header = names[i];

                var b = new Binding();
                b.Path = new PropertyPath(string.Format("obcItemsMeasured[{0}]", i)); // Binding is based on index into array, thats why all entries have to have the same dynamic fields
                b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

                c.Binding = b;

                dtgResults.Columns.Add(c);
            }

        }
        public IList<MyDimension> CreateData()
        {
            List<MyDimension> Dimensions = new List<MyDimension>();
            string[] names = new string[] { "PART11", "PART20" }; // They must all have the same obcItemsName/obcItemsMeasured entries, and in the same order
            Dimensions.Add(CreateItem("LOC1-X", names, 0, 0));
            Dimensions.Add(CreateItem("LOC1-Y", names, 0, 0));
            Dimensions.Add(CreateItem("LOC1-D", names, 10.0, 10.1));
            Dimensions.Add(CreateItem("LOC1-RN", names, 0, 0));
            Dimensions.Add(CreateItem("LOC2-X", names, 0, 0));
            Dimensions.Add(CreateItem("LOC2-Y", names, 0, 0));
            Dimensions.Add(CreateItem("LOC1-DF", names, 10.2, 10.3));
            Dimensions.Add(CreateItem("LOC2-TP", names, 0, 0));
            Dimensions.Add(CreateItem("DIST1-M", names, 14.14214, 14.14215));
            Dimensions.Add(CreateItem("DIST2-M", names, 10.4, 10.5));
            // etc...
            return Dimensions;
        }
        public MyDimension CreateItem(string name, string[] names, params double[] values)
        {
            var d = new MyDimension();
            d.NameAxisDimension = name;
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                d.obcItemsName.Add(names[i]);
                d.obcItemsMeasured.Add(values[i]);
            }
            return d;
        }
    }
    public class MyDimension
    {
        public MyDimension()
        {
            obcItemsName = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            obcItemsMeasured = new ObservableCollection<double>();
        }
        public string NameAxisDimension { get; set; }
        public double Nominal { get; set; }
        public double UpperTolerance { get; set; }
        public double LowerTolerance { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> obcItemsName;
        public ObservableCollection<double> obcItemsMeasured { get; set; } // Has to be a property since it is used in the binding
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am safe on the fact that all array have the same lenght. Your code produces the same problems that I noticed with CBreeze's solution. Please see my edit.

Comment: Did you change obcItemsMeasured to a property? It won't work if it's just a member field. Has to be a property for bindings to work.